# DLink dsl-g604t port forwarding inside network

Tags: nat, port-forwarding

I have a D-Link DSL-G604T. I have a dns that resolves a URL to its IP address.

I port forward port 80 to a computer. All works fine - except when I try to access that URL inside the network, instead of seeing the webpage I'm trying to view it just shows me the router's management webpage.

It's really annoying. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This is because the D-Link is effectively in a circular reference, because it knows:

1. The IP address for the website is the same IP address that the router has
2. Therefor I should route it to myself
3. This is coming from an **internal** IP address on a **LAN** port and it's routing to me, therefor they must be trying to access the management console
4. Show the management console

Whereas when you're external:

1. The IP address for the website is the same IP address that the router has
2. Therefor I should route it to myself
3. This is coming from an **external** IP address on a **WAN** port and it's routing to me, therefor I shall perform the port fowarding on it
4. Show the website

This is what happens with consumer-level routers that don't have any options for NAT reflection and are not smart enough to only respond to requests on their local IP address.

If you can, change the web interface on the D-Link to a different port (say, :81) and then you can log into is using http://192.168.0.1:81 (or whatever the IP address of the router is).